# FB OpenGraph og:image, link a folder?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm in the process of adding meta tags to a project, and I've been reading through the OpenGraph documentation, however every time I see `og:image` what comes next is always a URL. Is it possible to pass a file in instead with a relative path?

**File Structure:**

```
public
   index.html
   images
    staticimage.png
```

Can I just link to the image path?

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="./images/staticimage.png" />
```

So far it doesn't appear to be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative URLs will not work, the `og:image` property can only handle full URLs.

The `og:image` property does have some optional structured properties:

- `og:image:url` - Identical to og:image.
- `og:image:secure_url` - An alternate URL to use if the webpage requires HTTPS.
- `og:image:type` - A MIME type for this image.
- `og:image:width` - The number of pixels wide.
- `og:image:height` - The number of pixels high.
- `og:image:alt` - A description of what is in the image (not a caption). If the page specifies an og:image it should specify `og:image:alt`.

A full image example:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="A shiny red apple with a bite taken out" />
```

**Source:** https://ogp.me/#structured

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't see anything indicating about relative paths (I need to really engrain that term) so thought I would ask. Thank you!